# WireGuard is blocked by firewall

Tags: vpn, routing, wireguard

I decided to use wireguard as my VPN. Set up VPN server on VM machine.

VPN Server (10.13.13.1) <-> VPN Androind Client(10.13.13.6)
VPN Server (10.13.13.1) <- VPN Widnows Client (10.13.13.12)

Connection between Android works and can ping Server from android and android from server.

Connection between Windows and Server works partialy because from Client I can ping Server, but from Server I can not ping Windows Client. Firewall is problem here because when I turn It off ping works! I added rules to inbound and outbound rules and port 51820 (my VPN port) also. What am I doing wrong?

2023-03-13 12:46:05 DROP UDP 10.13.13.12 10.13.13.12 137 137 0 - - - - - - - SEND

2023-03-13 12:45:56 DROP ICMP 10.13.13.1 10.13.13.12 - - 84 - - - - 8 0 - RECEIVE

My client config files:

[Interface]
Address = 10.13.13.21
PrivateKey = XX
ListenPort = 51820
DNS = 10.13.13.1

[Peer]
PublicKey = XX
PresharedKey = XX
Endpoint = XX:XX:XX:XX:51820
AllowedIPs = 10.13.13.0/24 -> here only want to pass 10.13.13.0 network. I do not want to access 192.168.0.0 network throught VPN.